# AJAX POST not working in android studio webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, post

I have simple login page which uses `AJAX POST` the page works fine in the browsers. I have created an android studio project with the `web view` and given the link of the login page, I have also included `HTML 5` features for the page, but the login page does not send or receive any data when i run it on the android studio emulator.

The `AJAX POST CODE` is as follows

```js
var ins = empID + "~" + empPassword;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: "http://Servername/Service1.svc/json/EmpLogin",
  data: '{"EDetailslogin": "' + ins + '"}',
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: "json",
  processData: false,
  success: function(data) {
    widow.location.href = "Page2.html";
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert("User Not Recognized");

  }
});
```

The android manifest code is as follows

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.Myproj.Sample">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

My `Main Activity.java` file has the following code with the `HTML-5` features added to the page.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private WebView wv1;
  public String TAG;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    String url = "file:///android_asset/login.html";

    wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    WebSettings ws = wv1.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
      try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Enabling HTML5-Features");
        Method m1 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDomStorageEnabled", new Class[] {
          Boolean.TYPE
        });
        m1.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

        Method m2 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabaseEnabled", new Class[] {
          Boolean.TYPE
        });
        m2.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

        Method m3 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabasePath", new Class[] {
          String.class
        });
        m3.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/");

        Method m4 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheMaxSize", new Class[] {
          Long.TYPE
        });
        m4.invoke(ws, 1024 * 1024 * 8);

        Method m5 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCachePath", new Class[] {
          String.class
        });
        m5.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/cache/");

        Method m6 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheEnabled", new Class[] {
          Boolean.TYPE
        });
        m6.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Enabled HTML5-Features");
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
      }

    }
    wv1.loadUrl(url);
    //wv1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
  }

  private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
    }
  }


}
```

I have also Imported all the necessary class files. Still the application does not seem to work. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: "get" calls are working?

Comment: you might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756794/ajax-not-working-in-android-webview

Comment: I have a doubt here. So, I have my WCF server hosted using the IIS and in the url of the POST method I'm giving a locally hosted server address. Is it in anyway affecting the service? I just got this doubt now.

Comment: @new_user no the get calls are also not working.